# Как объединить таблицы в Yii2?

Tags: mysql, yii2, i18n

Смотрите какая проблема, есть сущности: категория, город, страна

[image: таблицы в базе данных]

Но для каждой сущности нужно по 2 таблицы создавать, потому что переводы нужно в отдельную таблицу хранить, чтоб потом можно было добавлять ещё языки не меняя структуру таблицы.

Вот таблица `category_translate`:

[image: category_translate]

Нужно создать отдельные модели для `category` и `category_translate` или это как-то объединить в одну модель?

Если можно объединить в одну модель то скиньте пожалуйста ссылку на подобный урок. (если есть)

Comment: Взгляни в сторону https://github.com/lajax/yii2-translate-manager. Там как раз идея в том, чтобы хранить языковые данные отдельно. Так проще добавлять/включать/выключать новые языки

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку.